# Authenticate users with LDAP and Apache 2.4

Tags: .htaccess, ldap, apache-2.4

i would like to setup a LDAP Authentication with Apache 2.4. LDAP Sever is a Windows 2008.

My **.htaccess** looks like:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login"
AuthBasicProvider      ldap
AuthLDAPBindDN         "CN=user,OU=Dienstkonten,DC=company,DC=lan"
AuthLDAPBindPassword   "pwd"
AuthLDAPURL            "ldap://dc.company.lan/DC=company,DC=lan?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" NONE

require ldap-group CN=Login-Group,OU=Dienstkonten,DC=company,DC=lan
```

But i get always the **error**:

```
(70023)This function has not been implemented on this platform: AH01277: LDAP: Unable to add rebind cross reference entry. Out of memory?
```

What do i wrong?
How can i authenticat users with ldap and apache 2.4?

Answer (score 6):

This solved this problem for me:

```
LDAPReferrals Off
```

Other tips gathered from [here](https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=4851&view=next) and [here](http://serverdown.ttwait.com/que/594366):

```
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
# Use the password without quotes, e.g. password instead of "password"
AuthLDAPBindPassword password
```

However, these were not necessary for me.

Answer (score 2):

> ldap://dc.company.lan/DC=company,DC=lan?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)

This filter appears to search the entire directory including every possible object class. Surely you can cut it down to whatever object class you are using for people?

Comment: I have been struggling so hard with the require ldap-group command, it never worked, but by trimming down the URL I let it search, I fixed that problem and removed a line of code! Great tip, thanks. I suppose I also made it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like an error coming from the Win AD you could either directly contact Microsoft and ask them for feedback.

Or you could prepare that step by first setting up a standard LDAP server (e.g. OpenLDAP), fill it with testdata corresponding to your AD contents) and test your setup against this LDAP server.

After successfully finishing that one try again with the AD. If that does not then you might setup OpenLDAP to provide the necessary "view" of the AD to have the application succeed.